# Is there a way by winapi to monitor the plugin/unplug event on a fixed USB HUB/Port location?

Tags: winapi, usb, monitor

I am looking for a way by using winapi to monitor a fixed USB HUB/Port location.

I can only find a way to monitor the Hardware Insertion and/or Removal as a general event. And then, I have to search again to find out if my interested device has been inserted to a fixed location, which is really time-consuming if I need to monitor several locations at the same time and devices might be inserted in a random manner.

Comment: Doesn't WM_DEVICECHANGE give you the info you need?

Comment: Thanks, but I think WM_DEVICECHANGE can only tell me an event of a class of devices but not an event happening to a certain USB location.